# RegExp test jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using some jQuery/JavaScript to detect the path name of the page and assign an `id` to its link within the navigation. It essentially changes the link text from black to blue.  Anyway, I've borrowed some of the code and I'm not advanced enough to figure out the `RegExp` test part, but when it passes the homepage as the path `/`, it assigns the `id` to all the links in the navigation (`/index.html` passes fine).  Can someone help me figure out why the test is not working properly on the path name `/`?

```
$(function() { 
    var url = window.location.pathname,  
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");

    $('.nav ul li a').each(function() {  
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))) {        
            $(this).attr('id', 'selected'); 
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        if (url === "/index.html" || url === "/") {
            $('.nav').attr('id','homenav');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you don't know regular expressions, how will you be able to tell when someone has provided a correct answer?

Comment: I'll test it to see if it works. I implemented a work around to set "/" equal to "/index.html" before the test and the code works now.  Still, I'd like to learn, but perhaps RegEx is a bit too far above my head right now--I'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To explain your situation

- when you are setting up 
  `urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");` you are first removing the trailing slash. This is done by your regex `/\/$/`.
- When you pass in / you will remove that slash and the resulting regex is `/$/`. This will match anything since all it is looking for is `$` (which in regex indicates the end of the string). A solution will likely involve handling the / case specifically (as you indicated you have already done and the solution above does).

If you want to mess around with regex I have found that a good resource is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Great explanation and resource, David. I appreciate you taking the time to explain what's happening - it makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

This should accomplish the same task:

```
var trailing_slash_re = /\/$/,
canon_url = location.pathname.replace(trailing_slash_re, '');

$('.nav ul li a').each(function() {
  var this_url = this.href.replace(trailing_slash_re, '');
  if (this_url.substr(-canon_url.length) == canon_url) {
    this.id = 'selected';
    return false; // don't process any others
  }
});
```

For each link it determines whether it ends with the `canon_url`. I'm jumping out of the loop once it has found an anchor that matches. This avoids multiple `selected` id's.

Comment: I like this code--it's much cleaner and dips into the DOM less often.  Nice optimization, Jack!